# Who are our top 50 news magazines?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Congratulations to scifi.stackexchange.com on being one of Time Magazine's 50 Best Websites of 2013!

[Link](http://techland.time.com/2013/05/06/50-best-websites-2013/slide/science-fiction-fantasy-stack-exchange/)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Very cool!  We're starting to hit the big time....

Comment: So that's why I've gotten a few late upvotes on my balrog answer...

Answer (score 9):

Wow, that's pretty cool. Maybe I CAN actually put that I'm a moderator on this site on my resume now... Hmmm...

Comment: On mine I can put that I was a mod before it became mainstream :p

Comment: @Gilles What's French for "hipster" ?

Comment: @JohnO "Gillés"

Comment: @JohnO [Comment traduire « hipster » ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1546/comment-traduire-hipster)

Comment: My Gollum ad made it into the picture! :D

Comment: @Slytherincess - does it point to the correct site now? :)

Answer (score -3):

Who's the newb who posted this dumb meta submission anyway? That image is clearly photoshopped (I can see the pixels), Time Magazine only concerns itself with important things, like bleeding readership and going into bankruptcy.

Comment: See http://techland.time.com/2013/05/06/50-best-websites-2013/slide/science-fiction-fantasy-stack-exchange/ for the reason I'm downvoting your answer...

Comment: Given who posted the OP, anyone downvoting this needs to  URGENTLY report to the nearest hospital for an urgent surgery to restore normal functioning of humour center.

Comment: While I'm not downvoting this (I get the humor, even if I don't necessarily think its as funny as DVK does), it probably should have been a comment, not an answer.  Then again, the question isn't really one that can be answered, either....

Comment: @Beofett - someone from Stack Exchange needs to change the "mod-only" tag on this Q from "discussion" to "status-completed". If only SE employees posted here...